# ООП и память, подскажите доступную для понимания статью

Tags: java, swift

Хотелось бы для саморазвития поглубже разобраться с тем как объекты хранятся в памяти, что с ними происходит во время работы приложения при объектно- ориентированном подходе в программировании.

Я имею примерное представление, но есть много вопросов. Например, если я передаю объект класса в качестве аргумента в функции, дублируется ли он в памяти, или просто передается ссылка на этот объект. Или, например, сильно ли влияет на производительность то что я разбиваю код одной функции на несколько функций для удобства.

Подскажите статью доступную для обычного программиста самоучки)) Можно на инглише, желательно на примере swift или Java. Самое главное, чтобы рассказывалось про работу памяти при ООП.

Comment: Мне кажется, что ключевой момент - это хранение экземпляров объектов в памяти и вообще структура памяти. ООП тут не при чем.

Comment: см. https://habrahabr.ru/post/134102/

Comment: @rvit34 спасибо, очень полезная ссылка.

Comment: Хорошая статья, объясняет принцип работы сборки мусора: https://ggenikus.github.io/blog/2014/05/04/gc/

Answer (score 1):

Head First Java O'REALLY очень неплохая книга для начала, есть она и на русском, там очень простым языком все описано, в том числе и про жизнь объекта и распределение памяти при выполнении инструкций кода.

Comment: Спасибо, поищу.

Answer (score 1):

Про передачу по ссылке и значению в Swift классах и структурах: https://www.objc.io/issues/16-swift/swift-classes-vs-structs/

А про выбор weak/strong мне все очень помогла эта статья:
https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift